# Accept Java input from console as well as from piping a text file

Tags: java, pipe, user-input

I want to make a function that accepts input from the user via the Console as well as when piping input from a text file (the latter for testing purposes).
So far the work-around I found is to overload the function.
the version with the input from text file:

```
void game_run(String inputFileStream, PrintStream out) throws IOException {

        int i=MAX_RETRY;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(inputFileStream),"UTF-8");
        String guessed_code = new String();
        System.out.println("insert input");
        if (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            guessed_code = sc.nextLine();
        }
        out.println(guessed_code);
}
```

And I call it in the main function as follows:

```
ms.game_run(args[1],System.out);
```

But when I want to run this from the command Line i have to pass the txt file as an argument to the programm like so :

`java MasterMild ..\tests\inputs-1.txt > resss`

And the second version just accepts normal Scanner:

```
void game_run() throws IOException {


        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); //The user inputs a value that gets stored
        System.out.printf("insert input");
        String guessed_code = new String(); //in the guessed_code variable
        if (sc.hasNext()) {
            guessed_code = sc.nextLine();
        }
```

Now I want to modify my code so that it accepts input from both the console and also from piping the input as a text file to the Programm, like this: 
`cat ../tests/inputs-1.txt | java MasterMild > results`

Comment: you will have to consider the input as file name, and read it. If  you get filenotfound exception, then consider it as string input

Comment: If you pipe from a text file, then the input you read on the console is the content of the text file. You have nothing else to do than reading from System.in.